# SQL запрос  на максимальное количество

Tags: mysql

Имеется табличка:

```
id|org_id|name|opinion|date|
1|1|какоетоназвание|1|2013-08-02
2|1|какоетоназвание|1|2013-08-01
3|2|какоетоназвание|0|2013-08-03
4|3|какоетоназвание|1|2013-08-04
5|3|какоетоназвание|0|2013-08-01
```

Вообще цель, вытащить `org_id` с максимальным кол-вом(`COUNT`) `opinion = 1`
Хотелось без циклов одним `sql` запросом, но в голову ни чего не лезет

Comment: SELECT MAX(counted) FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM fg_reviews
WHERE `date` > '2013-08-03'
) AS counts;
что то как то не так

Comment: @avengerweb Ну лучше бы двумя, а то приходится дублировать

    select org_id from (select org_id, count(*) cnt 
     from t 
     where opinion = 1 group by org_id) a 
     where a.cnt = (select max(cnt) 
       from (select count(*) cnt 
       from t where opinion = 1 group by org_id) b) ;

Дублируется запрос подсчёта opinion = 1 

Да, если таких максимумов несколько, то Вы получите их все.

За два (или три?) можно так

     create view v as select org_id, count(*) cnt from t where opinion = 1 group by org_id;
     select org_id from v where cnt = (select max(cnt) from v);
     drop view v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `org_id`, SUM(`opinion`) as `opinion`
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY `org_id`
ORDER BY `opinion` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[Рабочий пример на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1841a/5)